# How can I replace part of a matrix with a new matrix in torch

Tags: pytorch

Consider following matrices

```
>>> a = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> a
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.],
        [7., 8., 9.]])
>>> b = torch.tensor([[1,1],[1,1]])
>>> b
tensor([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]])
```

I want to replace 4 elements in a with b where their indices are specified in X = [0,2] and Y = [0,2]

To have:

```
>>>a
tensor([[1., 2., 1.],
        [4., 5., 6.],
        [1., 8., 1.]])
```

I look for some operations like scatter or put_index to update the matrix in few commands (not loops).

Comment: So to get the indices you do the outer product X.Y giving: `(x=0, y=0)`, `(x=0, y=2)`, `(x=2, y=0)`, and `(x=2, y=2)`?

Answer (score 0):

If we consider X and Y two tensors of horizontal and vertical indices, the following can work:

```
a[X.reshape(-1,1), Y] = b
```